# SD card writing fails?

Tags: java, android, inputstream, sd-card

Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong with this piece of code? Basically I want the app to download a .png file, display it to the user and also save it to the sd card for future reference. It seems to be all going fine until the `while ((len = webstream.read(buffer)) > 0)` part; as the debugger doesn't reach the breakpoint I've put in here, and I have a directory of empty .png files. I have the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission declared in my Manifest.

```
protected class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... string) {

        Bitmap d = null;

        try {

            DefaultHttpClient dhc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(HTTP_BASE + string[0] + ".png");
            HttpResponse response = dhc.execute(request);
            BufferedInputStream webstream = new BufferedInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent());
            d = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(webstream);
            writeToSd(string[0], webstream, d);

        }
        catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }

        return d;

    }

    private void writeToSd(String string, BufferedInputStream webstream, Bitmap d) {

        try {

            webstream.mark(3);
            webstream.reset();
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + SD_DIR);
            f.mkdirs();
            File f2 = new File(f, string + ".png");
            f2.createNewFile();
            BufferedOutputStream fos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f2));

            int len;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while ((len = webstream.read(buffer)) > 0) {

                fos.write(buffer, 0, len);

            }

            webstream.close();
            //fos.flush();
            fos.close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }


    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        if (result != null) {
            iv.setImageBitmap(result);
            vs.setDisplayedChild(1);
        }

    }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know for sure, but it seems likely that there is something wrong with the re-reading of the InputStream, even though it's buffered. An image is quite a bit of data to hold in memory. Rather than doing

> Fetch Image, Display Image, Store Image

you could try to

> Fetch Image, Store Image, Display Image

This way you can write a full-sized image to disk (without having to buffer the stream and consume a lot of memory). Then, you can simply load the image from the sd card at the lowest sampling rate that works for your application, thus saving having a full-sized image ever in memory. Also, doing it this way would likely eliminate any issues you may or may not be having with the bufferedInputStream - I find them to be pretty finicky.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want the original stream bytes, you can write the bitmap out to disk using [`Bitmap.compress(format, quality, stream)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29).

However, Hamy's answer is probably best from a memory conservation point of view.